# Hide parent element if span contains "(0)"

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div>Group 1
    <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="B"> <label>A<span>(34)</span></label>
    <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="I"> <label>B<span>(0)</span></label>
    <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="A"> <label>C<span>(323)</span></label>
    <br />
</div>
<div>Group 2
    <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="B"><label>A<span>(0)</span></label>
    <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="I"><label>B<span>(564)</span></label>
    <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="A"> <label>C<span>(0)</span></label>
    <br />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var checkname = $(this).attr("name");

    if (this.checked) {

        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").removeAttr("checked").parent().hide();
        this.checked = true;
        $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").parent().show();
    }

    if($(".options input:checkbox + label span:contains('(0)')")){
        $(this).parent().hide();;
    }else{
        $(this).parent().show();
    }
});


$("input:checkbox[checked]").trigger("change");
```

I would like to hide the checkbox with its label if the child span contains (0). You can see what I've tried above but it's not working. How to do it ?

http://jsfiddle.net/warface/uvYzW/4/

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do, removing attributes, setting them on the next line, hiding and showing the same element almost at the same time ?

Comment: I'm trying to hide checkboxes that have a span containing (0). That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: The code in the fiddle does not seem to match the code in the question at all.

Comment: You do know `<br>` is'nt really an element, it can't be opened and closed and contain other elements, so `parent` in your code is always the `div` ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to update the fiddle

Comment: Here's a fiddle with everything fixed -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B93nH/) ?

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, the filter function was the thing I was looking for ;)

Comment: @adeneo that's a lot of code to compensate for poor markup structure. The small markup change I recommended turns this into a very simple line of code. Just saying...

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble - you do realize the markup in my fiddle and your answer is the same ?

Comment: Ha ha, I didn't, sorry. Apologies for insulting your code, but this is far less expensive in syntax and cpu ticks: http://jsfiddle.net/p2XGq/

Comment: Are you saying `:contains()` is more efficient than a `filter()` ?

Comment: Are you trying to lead me into a trap?! But yes, I am saying in this case that contains could be more efficient as the differences are minimal and my selectors are less intensive: http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-vs-filter I'm honestly not trying to get into a p!ssing contest here, both solutions work just fine and in all honesty there's prob 100 cpu ticks and fewer milliseconds between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup:

```
<div>Group 1
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="B"> <label>A<span>(34)</span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="I"> <label>B<span>(0)</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("label span:contains('(0)')").closest("div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each( $("input[type=checkbox]") , function(key, value) {  
    var element = $(value);
    if (element.next().find("span").text()==="(0)") {               
        element.prev().hide();  // remove the <br>
        element.hide();
        element.next().hide(); // remove the label
    }   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hgg58/2/